# CSS3 : how to show heading only all the time even re-size window

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is there any option in responsive to show fixed part of div (heading only).
for example  `<strong>` content should should show in all window size.

Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/DXBRM/**

[image]

Comment: Have you heard of media queries?

Comment: @fatman the issue in media query. because most of the devices are different screen width

Comment: And how is that an issue? media queries can be made for any screen size.

Comment: @fatman 
you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/DXBRM/ when resize

Comment: @bboymaanu try min-height or max-height

Comment: @flangofas I think question gave misunderstanding Could you check question again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using media queries:

```
/*iPads -----------*/
    @media only screen
    and (min-width : 768px)
    and (max-width : 1024px)
    {
        strong{
            display: none;
            }
    }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qtpf9/)

Comment: I just wanna display only heading all the time. Rest of the lines should show when hover. Hope you understand the issue

Comment: this is just an example, to show you how you would go about it with media queries, inside the media query you can show/hide whatever you want

Comment: Actually no need to hide anything. Just wanna show `heading`` all the time rest of the line should show when hover on it. sorry for the misunderstanding of my question and also thank a lot for your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

I edit your jsfiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/DXBRM/3/

You can do it with javascript, i used jQuery for simplicity:

```
var Cheight = $(".colums").height();
$(".headline").css("bottom", - Cheight + 30);
$(".colums").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find(".headline").css("bottom", 0);
});
$(".colums").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".headline").css("bottom", - Cheight + 30);
});
```

I assume your headline is 30px height.

If you want it to work also when you resize window just use `$(window).resize(function(){...})`